# Using Conditional Logic Inside of an array.map in React

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm learning React and am using array.map to loop over an array of people and display information about them. I also need to display a message(`voterMessage`) with each person that is different depending on what that person's age is.

**I know I can do this with an inline ternary operator(since in this case I only have two options) but I want to do it with an if/else in case I need to add more options later.**

I can't figure out how and where to put this conditional to get it to work. I've moved the conditional to several places in the code and each time I get a different error. The code below is throwing an Unexpected Token error on line 12(the p tag right after the else statement).

Researching the issue only brings up ways to handle conditionals outside the return statement, methods of using ternary operators, and ways to access properties directly, but I can't find a way of doing it when the property is an array and the conditional must apply to each object in the array based on an object's property in that array.

```
const Person = (props) => {
    let voterMessage;
    return (
        
        <div>{props.people.map(p =>
            {if (p.age > 18) {
                voterMessage = "please go vote"
            } 
            else {
                voterMessage = "you must be 18"
            }}           
                <p>Learn some information about this person</p>
                <ul>
                    <li>Name: {p.name}</li>
                    <li>Age: {p.age}</li>
                    <h3>{voterMessage}</h3>
                </ul>
        )}</div>
    )
}
```

Comment: inside the map you need to return something. You are currently not returning anything from this function from what i can tell

Comment: you can write `const voterMesage = p.age > 18 ? 'please go vote' : 'you must be 18';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.map` is a function that requires you to return a value. It basically creates a new array from the values currently in it by transforming the already present values into something new. Your original function was a mess of curly brackets, so I thinned it down a bit. I'll remark that the `<h3>` in the `<ul>` tag bothers me, and I would assume it's not valid HTML, but I'll leave that up to you to figure out.

Another issue was that you were declaring the `voterMessage` variable *outside* of the map function, which would likely give you some bugs later on. Truthfully, however, you didn't need it. The statement that reads

```
 {p.age >= 18 ? 'Please go vote' : 'You must be 18'}
```

is called a [ternary expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). They are very useful when handling statements that depend on a variable and can only output one of two options.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

```js
const Person = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.people.map((p) => {
        let voterMessage;
        if (p.age >= 18) {
          voterMessage = "Please go vote";
        } else {
          voterMessage = "You must be 18";
        }

        return (
          <React.Fragment>
            <p>Learn some information about this person</p>
            <ul>
              <li>Name: {p.name}</li>
              <li>Age: {p.age}</li>
              <h3>{voterMessage}</h3>
            </ul>
          </React.Fragment>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

### EDIT

OP Specifically wants if/else in place of ternary. Updated code to reflect that, but leaving the ternary link in there for anyone else who may read this question.

Comment: I can do it with a ternary but as mentioned in the post I want to know how to get it done with an if/else in case I want to add more than 2 options later

Comment: Thank you! The updated code works perfectly. I didn't have to return anything out of the array.map on the last array I used it on but there wasn't any conditional logic so maybe that was it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: without seeing the code I'm assuming you were also using an arrow function for said map. If it was one line (or a one-line equivalent) then you wouldn't need to manually return something, as arrow functions will assume you mean to return the value given to them in the one line. e.g. `arr.map(v => v+1)` assumes that the return value is `v+1`. The moment you add in curly braces to the provided function is when you need to manually return something

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ternary if

remove this

```
{ if (p.age > 18) {
     voterMessage = "please go vote"
  }else {
     voterMessage = "you must be 18"
  }
}
```

and inside your h3 add

```
{p.age > 18 ? 'please go vote' : 'you must be 18'}
```

and if you want to have multiple if-else's, you can nest it

```
{p.age > 18 ? 'please go vote' 
 : p.age > 17 ? 'almost there' : 'Whats taking you so long' }
```

Comment: think you have a typo with the 19?

Comment: I can do it with a ternary but as mentioned in the post I want to know how to get it done with an if/else in case I want to add more than 2 options later

Comment: I See, what you can do is a nested ternary, but thats probably it, you can't use the if-else syntax, i'll update the example accordingly, but since you are using the "map" function you can the other solution which is perfectly fine, since you are passing a function anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

This design seems a bit confused. It doesn't make sense to have a component called `Person` that accepts an array of people as props. Each `Person` should be a distinct component and a collection of `People` is a better place to map over your array of data associated with people. This will make your error a bit easier to deal with (the fundamental problem is that you're attempting to toss JSX in outside of your function block).

For example:

```js
const Person = ({person: {name, age}}) =>
  <div>
    <p>Learn some information about this person</p>
    <ul>
      <li>Name: {name}</li>
      <li>Age: {age}</li>
    </ul>
    <h3>{age < 18 ? "you must be 18" : "please go vote"}</h3>
  </div>
;

const People = ({people}) =>
  <div>
    {people.map(e => <Person key={e.id} person={e} />)}
  </div>
;

const people = [
  {
    id: 1,
    age: 19,
    name: "tom",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    age: 15,
    name: "jerry",
  }
];

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app"))
  .render(<People people={people} />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

You mention you'd like to do this without a ternary. As it stands, that just makes the code verbose and more difficult to read, but here it is for comparison. I don't recommend coding like this.

```js
const Person = ({person: {name, age}}) => {
  let votingMessage = "please go vote";

  if (age < 18) {
    votingMessage = "you must be 18";
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Learn some information about this person</p> 
      <ul>
        <li>Name: {name}</li>
        <li>Age: {age}</li> 
      </ul>
      <h3>{votingMessage}</h3>
    </div>
  );
};

const People = ({people}) => 
  <div>
    {people.map(e => <Person key={e.id} person={e} />)}
  </div>;

const people = [
  {
    id: 1,
    age: 19,
    name: "tom",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    age: 15,
    name: "jerry",
  }
];

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app"))
  .render(<People people={people} />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```